# Do not receive meeting accepted email in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Some of the client computers we operate do not receive accepted meeting emails in Outlook.

Is there a setting option hidden somewhere that disables the meeting accepted notification receipt? The server logs do show the email in the system.

The problem is the meeting scheduler does not receive notification from anyone that accepted the meeting.

Thank you.

Edit: No delegates are setup. Outlook 2010.

Comment: Do any of the users that aren’t receiving notifications happen to have delegates setup?  What version of Outlook are you using?

Comment: Edited question to address your inquiry. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We determined the WSUS updates to Outlook , that we pushed on Thursday morning, changed something in the profiles. We declined about 30 of the updates and the feature works fine now.